# output all members of a form (form.FormController)

Tags: html, angularjs

Please see the code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/SmsRX9AlNefbccpDyLRW?p=preview)

it is an angular form, and the variable `form` should be of [FormController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) . As you see with the usage of `form.$pristine`, the variable `$pristine` exists in `form`, but why it doesn't output when I just try `<pre>form = {{form}}</pre>`. I wanted to see all the members (if possible function names, else at least all primitives like `$dirty`, `$valid` , etc.) Why it is not outputting in the `pre` tag and how can I show them? It is mainly for debugging, but curious as well.

```
<form novalidate name="form" class="simple-form">
    Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" /><br />
    E-mail: <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" /><br />
    Gender: <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="male" />male
    <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="female" />female<br />
    <button ng-click="reset()">RESET</button>
    <button ng-click="update(user)">SAVE</button>
  </form>
  <pre>pristine = {{form.$pristine}}</pre>
  <pre>form = {{form}}</pre>
```

### output

```
pristine = true
form = {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An expression like this: `{{form}}` will convert the form object to a string. Angular uses the build in `angular.toJson` function to serialize the object. Please have a look at the documentation: [angular.toJson](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson). As you can see there all properties with a leading `$` are stripped.

How to solve your problem:

You may use the JSON.stringify function to get all properties. Because you can't call this function in an expression you need to provide a helper function in your controller:

```
$scope.stringify = function(obj){
   return JSON.stringify(obj);
}
```

Now you are able to output your complete form object in the view:

```
{{stringify(form)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should also work...

```
<pre>form = {{form | json}}</pre>
```